# Make a json from string separated by hyphen arrow (->)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like "first->second->third->fourth..." and so on.

I need to convert it into tree like structre

```
[
 {
  "title":"first",
  "children":[
     {
        "title":"second",
        "children":[
           {
              "title":"third",
              "children":[
                 {
                    "title":"fourth"
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

How can I put loops for this.
**Last child will not have children**

Comment: Show us what you have tried to do this yourself

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Split and map....

Comment: Use `split` to convert string to array. And then `reduceRight` to build desired structure bottom to top.

Comment: `structure = "first->second->third->fourth";
splitted = structure.split("->")
var arrayStructure = [];
function appendNode(title){
    var node = {title : title, isFolder : true};
    if(arrayStructure[0]){
            arrayStructure[0].children = []
            node.children = [];
            node.isLazy = true;
            arrayStructure[0].children.push(node)
        }
    else{
        arrayStructure.push(node)
        arrayStructure[0].children = []
    }
}

for(i = 0 ; i<splitted.length; i++){
    appendNode(splitted[i])
}`

Comment: but here it is not digging deep into children as new node is about to add

Comment: @PankajShinde I got an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is an working example**

```js
function createOutput(string, delimiter) {
  var stringArray = string.split(delimiter).reverse(),
    output = {},
    i = stringArray.length - 1;
  
  output.title = stringArray[i];
  if (i - 1 >= 0) {
    stringArray.splice(i, 1);
    output.children = [];
    output.children.push(createOutput(stringArray.reverse().join(delimiter), delimiter));
  }

  return output;
}

var output = createOutput("first->second->third->fourth", "->");

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much...working fine... :)